# Node 18.17.1 Windows built-in filesystem watcher crashes

Tags: node.js, windows

When trying to run nodejs with `--watch` on Windows, sometimes its built-in filesystem watcher crashes silently, and other times it crashes with the following error message:

```
node:internal/validators:162
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received null
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:496:5)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
    at resolve (node:path:167:9)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (node:internal/watch_mode/files_watcher:98:30)
    at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:215:12) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

I have not been able to find a similar stacktrace anywhere else online.

Something that might complicate matters is that my project setup has two watchers: esbuild is watching input files, and nodejs is watching the output of esbuild. It seems that this second watcher is failing a lot. I have not been able to reproduce on my Mac or Linux systems that I have available, so it also seems this is a Windows-specific bug.

Does anyone know how I could get these watchers to work properly on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue as well, and it looks like this was [fixed](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/49891) in [Node 21.6.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V21.md#21.6.0), which was released recently.