# Node --watch crashes on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, crash, watch

My node crashes several times a day with this error message

> node:internal/validators:162
> throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
> ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "paths[1]" argument must be of
> type string. Received null
> at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
> at resolve (node:path:171:9)
> at FSWatcher. (node:internal/watch_mode/files_watcher:101:30)
> at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:515:28)
> at FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:215:12) {   code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE' }

I'm tried several versions of node and it crashes with all of them. I'm using --watch option on Windows 10-64bit and run it through VSC terminal.

I found a related question but without any answer... Anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: does it happen in terminals other than VS Code's? also, please add version info for all your things.

Comment: @starball
Nodes :  19.9.0 & 20.9.0 & 21.1.0 & 21.2.0 (all of them has same issue)
Windows 10-64bit 22H2
 It also crashes in regular Windows terminal so it doesn't look related to VSC

Comment: Same here :-\ Did you find a solution @Gabriel?

Comment: I didn't find any solution so i gave up and went back to nodemon. I also noticed that nodemon is also way faster to restart when the project goes bigger anyway. @georgiosd

Comment: I'm getting the same error, before I was using nodemon but I want to try what Node brings again, in my opinion it's just a bug and I don't know if it's reproducible for you, but if I have my index.js open and any another file and I am using --watch and I close this file (even without having modified a line) it shows this problem (possibly the same is repeated for other files). I imagine that in a few (future) LTS versions it could be resolved (something around 22). Until now, it may be more viable (depending on the size of the project to use nodemon).

Comment: I upgraded to latest node and it seems to work, or at least not fail EVERY time.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/77831450/4086196, it seems this was fixed in https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/49891